React Native IOS Expo test flight build crash on launch
Date/Time:           2024-04-10 17:48:16.6785 +1000
Launch Time:         2024-04-10 17:48:16.1961 +1000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.5 (21F5048f)
Release Type:        Beta
Baseband Version:    2.60.00
Report Version:      104
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: LocalFoxGetJobDone [2919]
Triggered by
Thread:  5
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18f43bf24 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:249)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1872de018 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   LocalFoxGetJobDone              0x100c97c08 RCTFatal + 568 (RCTAssert.m:147)
3   LocalFoxGetJobDone              0x100d095d0 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:] + 488 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:82)
4   LocalFoxGetJobDone              0x100d09de0 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1304 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:154)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x18f3d8854 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                  0x18f3d78a0 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428 (NSForwarding.m:3411)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x18f44e1dc -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64 (NSForwarding.m:3508)
8   LocalFoxGetJobDone              0x100cc9548 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 388 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   LocalFoxGetJobDone              0x100ccb64c facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 456 (RCTNativeModule.mm:196)
10  LocalFoxGetJobDone              0x100ccb29c facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const + 68 (RCTNativeModule.mm:113)
11  LocalFoxGetJobDone              0x100ccb29c invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 112 (RCTNativeModule.mm:104)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1972c513c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1530)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1972c6dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:576)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1972ce400 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748 (queue.c:3900)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1972cef30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380 (queue.c:3991)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1972d9cb4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288 (queue.c:6998)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x1972d9528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404 (queue.c:6592)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1ec7de934 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2696)
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1ec7db0cc start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a96808 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a9a008 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a99f20 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a99d60 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f40bf9c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f40b640 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f40ad18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   GraphicsServices                0x00000001d487d1a8 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
8   UIKitCore                       0x0000000191a45fac -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3713)
9   UIKitCore                       0x0000000191af9ed8 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5303)
10  LocalFoxGetJobDone              0x0000000100b2440c main + 80 (main.m:7)
11  dyld                            0x00000001b371ce4c start + 2240 (dyldMain.cpp:1298)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8aa142c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7e1c0c pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1721)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019737fba0 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ec600ca4 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ec5f0e5c demangling_terminate_handler() + 348 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:77)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001872f9e2c _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:496)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ec600068 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ec60000c std::terminate() + 108 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001972c6de8 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:579)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001972ce400 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748 (queue.c:3900)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001972cef30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380 (queue.c:3991)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001972d9cb4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288 (queue.c:6998)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001972d9528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404 (queue.c:6592)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7de934 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2696)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0cc start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a96808 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a9a008 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a99f20 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a99d60 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f40bf9c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f40b640 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f40ad18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   Foundation                      0x000000018e32ce4c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018e32cc9c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
9   UIKitCore                       0x0000000191a59ce0 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 420 (UIEventFetcher.m:1207)
10  Foundation                      0x000000018e343718 __NSThread__start__ + 732 (NSThread.m:991)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7e006c _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0d8 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a96808 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a9a008 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a99f20 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a99d60 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f40bf9c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f40b640 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f40ad18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   LocalFoxGetJobDone              0x0000000100cabc38 +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 212 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:332)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018e343718 __NSThread__start__ + 732 (NSThread.m:991)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7e006c _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0d8 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a9c1cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7dd6e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019f8eb504 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28 (condition_variable.cpp:45)
3   hermes                          0x0000000101f14108 hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::worker() + 316
4   hermes                          0x0000000101f13fa8 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v15006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::Exec... + 44
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7e006c _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0d8 thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d8a9c1cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7dd6e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019f8eb504 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28 (condition_variable.cpp:45)
3   hermes                          0x0000000101f14108 hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::worker() + 316
4   hermes                          0x0000000101f13fa8 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v15006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::Exec... + 44
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7e006c _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec7db0d8 thread_start + 8


Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001ec6052c3   x5: 0x000000016f596810   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0xf7eecbac17b4a865   x9: 0xf7eecbad78edd865  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000016f596340
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x00000000001ff800  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016f597000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000002503  x21: 0x000000016f5970e0  x22: 0x0000000000000114  x23: 0x000000016f5970e0
   x24: 0x000000030381f268  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000300348640
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016f596780   lr: 0x00000001ec7e1c0c
    sp: 0x000000016f596760   pc: 0x00000001d8aa142c cpsr: 0x40001000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
        0x100b20000 -         0x100fd7fff LocalFoxGetJobDone arm64  <17c61c0f4c08393184e89edd8e40af9f> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB1C9145-806A-42E9-B737-4FA9C072E6B7/LocalFoxGetJobDone.app/LocalFoxGetJobDone
        0x1011f4000 -         0x1011fffff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <2e2c05f8377a30899ad91926d284dd03> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
        0x101e48000 -         0x102017fff hermes arm64  <35fecc83959934c1813ef020b2d0d382> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB1C9145-806A-42E9-B737-4FA9C072E6B7/LocalFoxGetJobDone.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/hermes
        0x1872c8000 -         0x187315f43 libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <53115e1fe35330d99e8a4e6e73489f05> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
        0x18e265000 -         0x18eddafff Foundation arm64e  <70813f347ba4323f9815a878ec22047e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
        0x18f3b8000 -         0x18f8e5fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <17320d9047af3a0fa9712da7993fed01> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
        0x19163d000 -         0x193152fff UIKitCore arm64e  <4bc4a129ce5e32109d5838d642c7ca99> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
        0x1972c3000 -         0x197309fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <f2f2b992ccae3257848b52f6fc07098c> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
        0x19730a000 -         0x197387ff3 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <f57b5715e40639aabcc300db255b819d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
        0x19f8de000 -         0x19f967fff libc++.1.dylib arm64e  <badf6383449432f297ef716ea17420f6> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
        0x1b36e0000 -         0x1b376cef7 dyld arm64e  <3aa1ad27e9c635d8aa64627a0d1ad8d5> /usr/lib/dyld
        0x1d487c000 -         0x1d4884fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <92d1f86967dd3ee5b5dd10dc76d64896> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
        0x1d8a95000 -         0x1d8acefff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <4da0946f67c834b29b3c4c9e1ee5773a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
        0x1ec5ec000 -         0x1ec607ffb libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <f603d156e9c5356380a6d2ebedc07a02> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
        0x1ec7da000 -         0x1ec7e6ff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <19e4983d5ae937f49af4a717a5dfadd1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
        0x1ff380000 -         0x2004fbfe7 libLAPACK.dylib arm64e  <c551f3a9e92232b4afdb2342680d8381> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib

EOF


  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "expo": "^50.0.0-preview.10",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "metro": "0.80.4",
    "metro-config": "0.80.4",
    "metro-resolver": "0.80.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.12.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-heroicons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.0.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.1",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.0"
  },

This is the package.json
I think it is a package dependency issue.

Try running npx expo install --fix to fix dependencies.

It says:
"Dependencies are up to date"
But even the build crashes in the test flight

I noticed that you're encountering the same problem I recently faced. In my case, I discovered that the issue was caused by the "reactotron-react-native" library. After spending some time troubleshooting, I found that removing this library from my project resolved the problem.

The issue was regarding the navigation since I was using the older version and which was deprecated it was crashing on lauch.
